# Using 6 subfigures in one figure, missing number?

Tags: subfig

I have the following code:

```
usepackage{subfigure,subcaption,caption}

    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
            \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=1.2in]{Canada.png}
                \caption{Canada}
            \end{subfigure}
            \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=1.2in]{US.png}
                \caption{United States}
            \end{subfigure}
            \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=1.2in]{UK.png}
                \caption{United Kingdom}
            \end{subfigure}
            ~
            \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=1.2in]{China.png}
                \caption{China}
            \end{subfigure}
            \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=1.2in]{India.png}
                \caption{India}
            \end{subfigure}
            \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=1.2in]{Brazil.png}
                \caption{Brazil}
            \end{subfigure}
        \caption{2010 - 2016\\ source: \citep{source}}
    \end{figure}
```

which gives the following error in line with the `\begin{subfigure}...`: "Missing number, treated as zero. Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). I can't for the life of me understand whats wrong as I copied this from a previous project I created and just placed different graphics and added 2 more and changed the measurement of each subfigure to `{0.32\textwidth}` from the prior `{0.45\textwidth}`. Is there something functionally different about using 6 figures rather than 4? I don't see why there would be

Comment: The `subfigure` and the `subcaption` package are not compatible with each other. You should get an error message informing you about this. To fix this, remove the `subfigure` package from your preamble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I addition to heeding @leandriis' advice and not loading the deprecated `subfigure` package, you may also want to get rid of all 7 `\centering` instructions and replace all 6 instances of `height=1.2in` with `width=\textwith`. Throw in a couple of `\hfill` directives on each row and a `\bigskip` directive *between* the rows, and you'll get this look:

[image]

The reason why I recommend against the `height=1.2in` option is that it provides no guarantee that the graphs will actually fit inside the available space.

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % omit 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx,natbib}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
       \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Canada.png}
       \caption{Canada}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
       \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{US.png}
       \caption{United States}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
       \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{UK.png}
       \caption{United Kingdom}
    \end{subfigure}

    \bigskip % <-- new
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
       \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{China.png}
       \caption{China}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
       \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{India.png}
       \caption{India}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
       \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Brazil.png}
       \caption{Brazil}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{2010--2016\\source: \citep{source}}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```